# Local notification with countdown timer

Tags: android, notifications

I've seen few (I assume that they're local) notifications on android phones that shows title like:

`Appname - 1:23:12`

Where "1:23:12" is countdown timer changing every second. How I can do that? Normally I just see time notification was created.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a notification and utilize a timer that ticks every 1 second.  At each second, you can update your notification:

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Updating

You would build this out utilizing a foreground service.  There are a few approaches for the 1s tick:

RxJava:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(this::updateNotification)
```

Where `updateNotification` is a function that takes a `long` n which is the number of seconds that have passed, and updates your Notification via its id with the new countdown time.

You could also utilize a scheduled handler like:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Runnable updateRunnable = () -> {
    updateNotification();
    handler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 1000);
}

/* when you start the service... */
handler.post(updateRunnable);
```

Note that you'll need to do this in a Foreground Service.